# how to put scatter plot in front of bar plot when both are displayed in the same graph

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot

I'm using coreplot on IOS. I'm displaying in the same graph a scatter plot and a bar plot. When they are displayed the bar plot is on the top of the screen and as a consequence I cannot really see the scatter plot that is behind. I would like to put the scatter plot in foreground.

How can I do that?

See me code below. Any help will be appreciated

```
    // Create barChart from theme
barChart = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]; //  
[barChart applyTheme:theme];

theHostingView.hostedGraph = barChart;

// Border
barChart.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
barChart.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius    = 0.0f;

// Paddings
barChart.paddingLeft   = 0.0f;
barChart.paddingRight  = 0.0f;
barChart.paddingTop    = 0.0f;
barChart.paddingBottom = 0.0f;

// Offset pour placer les coordoonees du graph
barChart.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 70.0;
barChart.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 20.0;
barChart.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 15.0;
barChart.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 35.0;

// Graph title
[self configureTitle];


// Add plot space for horizontal bar charts
_plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)barChart.defaultPlotSpace;

float minAxis = 0.0;
if ([_theKPI.unit isEqualToString:@"%"]) {
    float intervalSize = ((_maxValue - minAxis)/100.0)/4;

    minAxis = _minValue - intervalSize;
    if (minAxis <= 0) {
        minAxis = 0.0;
    }

    _plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(minAxis/100.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((_maxValue - minAxis)/100.0)];

} else {

    if (_minValue >= 0) {
        _plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(_maxValue)];
    } else {
        _plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(_minValue)];
    }
}


CPTXYAxis* xAxis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTXYAxis* yAxis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
xAxis.plotSpace = _plotSpace;
yAxis.plotSpace = _plotSpace;

[self configureXAxis:xAxis min:minAxis plotSpace:_plotSpace];
[self configureYAxis:yAxis min:minAxis];


CPTXYPlotSpace* secondPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
secondPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50.0)];
[self configurePlotSpace:secondPlotSpace];


[barChart addPlotSpace:secondPlotSpace];

CPTXYAxis* yRightAxis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
yRightAxis.plotSpace = secondPlotSpace;
[self configureYRightAxis:yRightAxis];

barChart.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:xAxis, yAxis, yRightAxis, nil];

// Configure the Scatter Plot
_plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
_plot.dataSource = self;
_plot.identifier = @"mainplot";

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
_plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

CPTPlotSymbol* greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
_plot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;


// Configure the Bar Plot
_barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
_barPlot.baseValue  = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
_barPlot.dataSource = self;
_barPlot.delegate = self;
_barPlot.barOffset  = CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.25f);
_barPlot.identifier = @"Bar Plot 1";


[barChart addPlot:_plot toPlotSpace:secondPlotSpace];
[barChart addPlot:_barPlot];
```

Seb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last plot added to the graph will be displayed in front:

```
[barChart addPlot:_barPlot];
[barChart addPlot:_plot toPlotSpace:secondPlotSpace];
```

Comment: It was the first thing I tried but you are perfectly right! Due to several errors in my code it was not working. Thanks to your answer I have checked again and found the mistakes!!!